# R: what is a meaning of this error message in a user-defined function?

Tags: r

I'm working on a homework question that asks me to write a function that will graph different types of plots based on input data.

The arguments to the function are **`x`**, **`y`**, and **`type`**, where `x` and `y` are the vectors I want to plot and `type` is the type of plot (scatter, box, or histogram).

The function needs to be written so that if you don't specify data for `x` with type scatterplot, you get an error message saying that you need x data to make a scatterplot.

Likewise, if you do specify data for `x` with the type histogram or boxplot, you get an error message saying that you only need y data for these plot types.

I have a function written that produces the correct graphs and error messages, but also gives me a **warning message**:

```
In if (y == FALSE & type == 1) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The function is below. Can somebody tell me why I'm getting this particular warning?

```
plot.function2=function(x=FALSE,y=FALSE,type){
  if(x==FALSE & type==1){
    stop("Error Message 1")
  }else if (y==FALSE & type==1){
    stop("Error Message 1.5")
  }else if(type==1){
    plot=plot(y~x) 
  }else if (x==TRUE & type==2){
    stop("Error Message 2")
  }else if(type==2){
    plot=boxplot(y)
  }else if(type==3){
    plot=barplot(y)
  }

plot
}
```

The message shows up for most inputs; for instance, entering `plot.function2(v1, v2, 1)` gets me a scatterplot of the two vectors, **but also** the warning message. Thanks!

Comment: That nested `if`/`else` is painful to read. Have a look at the `switch` function. You can switch according to type and test input validity after this switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing vectors to boolean with your function.

```
# Here if you provide a vector x, you are essentially checking
# if each element is TRUE, hence the warning

  if(x==FALSE & type==1){
    stop("Error Message 1")
  }
```

As an example, see a vector from the iris dataset

```
> iris[1:25,1] == TRUE
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You should use `NULL` and `is.null` to see if the object is empty

```
plot.function2=function(x=NULL,y=NULL,type){
  if(is.null(x) & type==1){
    stop("Error Message 1")
  }else if (is.null(y) & type==1){
    stop("Error Message 1.5")
  }else if(type==1){
    plot=plot(y~x) 
  }else if (is.null(x) & type==2){
    stop("Error Message 2")
  }else if(type==2){
    plot=boxplot(y)
  }else if(type==3){
    plot=barplot(y)
  }
plot
}
```

As per a suggestion, this could be cleaned up with a `switch` statement which as you can see .

```
plot.function2=function(x=NULL,y=NULL,type){  
  # check if nulls
  if(is.null(y)){
    stop("You need to provide y data!!!")
  }
  if(is.null(x) & type == 1){
    stop("You need to provide x data!!!")
  }

  plot <- switch(as.character(type),
                 "1" = plot(y~x),
                 "2" = boxplot(y),
                 "3" = barplot(y))
  plot
}
```

Comment: You don't need `is.null(x)==TRUE`, just `is.null(x)` is sufficient.